# My stored procedure is vulnerable i think

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I am running an ASP.NET MVC app on SQL Server which seems to have been hacked or SQL injected. The database keeps creating tons of new fake accounts daily, I haven't fully identified the problem yet but I am worried about my stored procedure code which I previously thought was immune to SQL Injection.

Below is three shorted versions of my stored procedure code, PLEASE help me correct it if its vulnerable, Thank you.

Creating a new user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NEWUSER]
@Name varchar(50),
@Email varchar(70),
@Language varchar(20)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.User (name, email, language)
VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Language);

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

INSERT INTO dbo.Names (name)
VALUES (@Name);

SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Selecting a user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETUSER] 
@Name varchar(33)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT name, email, language FROM dbo.User WHERE name = @Name;
```

Update user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EDITUSER] 
@Name varchar(33),
@Email varchar(70)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE dbo.User SET email = @Email WHERE name = @Name;
```

Please help me fix this, I would really appreciate it.

My ASP.NET Code: http://www.cindro.com/all/database.txt

Comment: I don't think what you have is injectable, but from your problem description it sounds like `dbo.NEWUSER` is just being called a bunch of times. Maybe by a bot hitting your registration page?

Comment: It is likely your ASP.NET code that is vulnerable, not your stored procedure.

Comment: post your asp.net code

Comment: http://www.cindro.com/all/database.txt

Comment: One thing to remember is: if your server has ever been compromised (eg with a vulnerability you have since fixed) you can't guarantee there is no back door or other way in.

Comment: My ASP.NET Code: http://www.cindro.com/all/database.txt my code is solid right?

Answer (score 2):

Your stored procedures look ok. I'd try looking in your application code somewhere.

1. Do you have captcha in your forms?
2. Do you perform any server side validation?
3. Do you check of IP address where request is coming from?
4. Do you check if request is coming from a real browser or some script (Request.Browser.Cookies Request.Browser.Crawler) ?

Comment: Yes I have captcha, i do perform server side validation, I don't check for IP address and I don't check if the request is coming a browser or script.

Comment: A malicious bot is going to  disguise itself as a normal browser so Request.Browser.Crawler is going to  return false.